# Could not load file or assembly - reflection insist loading an old version

Tags: c#, .net

I got the following error when running a unit test in Visual Studio (2013).

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Newtonsoft.Json is a DLL that I referenced. But interestingly I referenced to Newtonsoft.Json 7.0 in all places. I was confused why reflection insisted loading an older version 6.0.

Any hint on where could I start to investigate?

Thanks,

Comment: use fuslogvw to see where it is finding the old file

Comment: Check to ensure you have marked the reference with 'Copy Local = true' if you have referenced the DLL directly.

Comment: Thanks @pm100 for suggestion. fulslogvw did work, it just took a LOT time to start working. So need to be patient at the first time. And it did show me where the old version is called - I built 6.0 version in a library, and built 7.0 version in the current project. I have two options: 1) use <bindingRedirect> as Gwasshoppa suggested; 2) modify all references to use the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your `web.config` file to see if there is something that is referencing the old version.

You can also try this adding this in the `web.config` to ensure the correct version is used. I would put this in just after the `<system.web>` tag

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>

        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes adding this section to app.config (since I am running a unit test instead of a web service) would work. I just tried to find out where the old version was called.